# How to use a basic SAS Macro Array?

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

**Beginner question:** I am trying to use SAS macro arrays as explained in this article: http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi31/040-31.pdf, specifically in the section `%ARRAY WITH DATA= AND VAR=`. Unfortunately there are no examples of a full program using this, and I can't find any simple examples online. I tried to create a simple example, guessing at some things, but it didn't work. (I got two errors for each macro: "Apparent invocation of macro ARRAY not resolved." and "Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.") What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
data data1;
input variable1;
datalines;
1
2
3
4
run;

%array(array1, data=data1, var=variable1);

%do_over(array1, phrase=PROC PRINT DATA=data1(obs=?));
run;
```

(Also, does anyone know the name of the SAS website which is sort of like this one? I remember seeing it but I can't find it again.)

Thanks!

Comment: runsubmit.com is the 'SAS website which is sort of like this one' :)

Comment: Yes, that is the one I was thinking of, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download a zip file with the macros at the SAS Community website: http://www.sascommunity.org/wiki/Tight_Looping_with_Macro_Arrays

Include them in your SAS program and it should work.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize originally that the array macros were not originally installed in SAS. thanks!

Comment: OK the program I posted works now, but I am having problems with %do_over. When I try to include two connected statements within a phrase, such as `data dataset2; set dataset1;` it doesn't recognise the second one as being connected to the first, and thus doesn't understand the second one at all. Do you know if there is any way around this? Thanks!